# Is there a way to work with files from a dictionary with similar names (numeric difference) in a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary

I was wondering if there could be a way to use files from a dictionary with similar names in a loop.

I have this dictionaries:

```
dcm = {}
for filename in os.listdir('./GMATfiles'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename,'DCM_hydra*.txt'):
       dcm[filename[:11]] = os.path.normpath(''.join(['./GMATfiles', '/', filename]))
       #print(dcm)

#OUT_INPUT
out={}
for filename in os.listdir('./GMATfiles'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename,'Out_hydra*.txt'):
       out[filename[:11]] = os.path.normpath(''.join(['./GMATfiles', '/', filename]))
       #print(out) 
#MATRIX_INPUT 
mtr={}
for filename in os.listdir('./GMATfiles'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename,'matrizr_hydra*.txt'):
       mtr[filename[:15]] = os.path.normpath(''.join(['./GMATfiles', '/', filename]))
       #print(mtr)
```

The names I get from each one of these dictionaries are the same except for a number (for example: DCM_hydra01, DCM_hydra02, DCM_hydra03 etc.)

Then I need to use these files from the dictionaries in some functions:

```
IFOV1= gi.IFOV_generic(out['Out_hydra01'],mtr['matrizr_hydra01'], dcm['DCM_hydra01'],'ifovfile_hydra1', endpoint)
IFOV2= gi.IFOV_generic(out['Out_hydra02'],mtr['matrizr_hydra02'], dcm['DCM_hydra02'],'ifovfile_hydra2',endpoint)
.
.
.
```

Is there a way to write a loop that would let me get these IFOV functions without the need of writing them one by one?

Someone already told me to use `zip()` as this:

```
dcm = {'f1': 'path_to_file'}
out = {'f1': 'path_to_file'}
mtr = {'f1': 'path_to_file'}

IFOV = []

for d, o, m in zip(dcm, out, mtr):
    IFOV.append(
        gi.IFOV_generic(out[o], mtr[m], dcm[d], endpoint)
    )
```

But I need to get the name os the file ('ifovfile_hydra*'), and I'm not sure this code can do that.

Comment: you could keep values using the same key - `out["01"]`, `mtr["01"]`, `dcm["01"]` and then you can easier get them - `key = "01"` and `out[key]`, `mtr[key]`, `dcm[key]`, and `"ifovfile_hydra" + int(key)` to get `"ifovfile_hydra1"` or `"ifovfile_hydra" + key` if you prefer `"ifovfile_hydra01"`

Comment: Rather than having three dictionaries, you could group these items together in a nested dictionary. Format would be something like: `{"hydra01": {"out": ..., "matrizr": ..., "DCM": ...}, "hydra02: {"out": ..., "matrizr": ..., "DCM": ...}, ...}`

Answer (score 0):

"Index" in a dictionary is a string, so yeah, we can do about anything with it!

The snippet you was given, should work as intended and it doesn't actually play with inserting numbers to the string! Just a small fix for the final name:

```
dcm = {'f1': 'path_to_file'}
out = {'f1': 'path_to_file'}
mtr = {'f1': 'path_to_file'}

IFOV = []

for d, o, m in zip(dcm, out, mtr):
    IFOV.append(
        gi.IFOV_generic(out[o], mtr[m], dcm[d], 'ifovfile_hydra'+o[-2:], endpoint)
    )
```

Dictionary by default iterates over the keys only. In your case, file names.

By zipping, you combine 1st key of the 1st dict with 1st key from the 2nd dict and with 1st key of the 3rd dict.

Then `for` loop iterates over those 3-element groups and gets their contents into separate variables. They still contain their respective file names.

`'ifovfile_hydra'+o[-2:]` - `o[-2:]` takes the last two characters from the string `o` ('Out_hydra01', 'Out_hydra02'...).

The only problem with that code would be if the files were not in order (e.g. 1st dict order is 03, 01, 02, while 2nd and 3rd are "correct"). This can be fixed by making `dmc = dict(sorted(dcm.items())` and so on - in newer Python, dictionaries' contents keep the order of insertion, so this snippet converts the dict to a list, sorts it and converts it back to dict (will work on lexicographical order, so "a10" < "a2", but with 0-padded numbers it's correct: "a10" > "a02").

---

Another thing would be to really fill in the number in a string.

```
for i in range(1, len(dcm)):
    IFOX.append(
        gi.IFOV_generic(out['Out_hydra{:02d}'.format(i)], met['matrizr_hydra{:02d}'.format(i)], dcm['DCM_hydra{:02d}'.format(i)],'ifovfile_hydra{:02d}'.format(i),  endpoint)
    )
```

`:02d` part means it's a 0-padded to 2 digits.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you just populate IFOV directly in the same loop that you read the files. But if you don't want to do that, then I suggest creating a single dictionary instead and only looping through the files once:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pathlib import Path

# If you're not on python 3.7, replace this with a function that makes a dict
@dataclass
class GmatFiles:
    dcm: str = ""
    out: str = ""
    mtr: str = ""


files = defaultdict(GmatFiles)
for filepath in Path("./GMATfiles".glob("*.txt"):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename,'DCM_hydra*.txt'):
        files[filepath.name[9:11]].dcm = filepath
    elif nmatch.fnmatch(filename,'Out_hydra*.txt'):
        files[filepath.name[9:11]].out = filepath
    elif fnmatch.fnmatch(filename,'matrizr_hydra*.txt'):
        files[filepath.name[13:15]].mtr = filepath

IFOV = []  
for item in files.values():
    IFOV.append(
        dcm = files[k
        gi.IFOV_generic(item.out, item.mtr, item.dcm, endpoint)
    )
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! I tried to do that but I get this error: ``` dcm: str = "" SyntaxError: invalid syntax ```

Comment: @novich What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 3.5.2, I should upgrade it?

Comment: You should if you can. But if you can't, read the comment where I said you can't use that without 3.7. Instead, make a function that initializes and empty dict with the keys. Or google how to make a data class before 3.7. 3.6 came with f-strings, I'd update for that alone.